# Would it be possible to display a product's price only to logged-in users based on the vendor in CS cart?

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, add-on, cs-cart

i am using cs cart for e-eCommerce website which is support multi vendor functionality and every vendor have some product and some have in thousands. so my question is how can i hide *add to cart* and *hide price* if user not logged in.

i am also aware of cs cart

> Allow shopping for unlogged customers:

setting which is under **setting > checkout** this setting globally enable and disable product price but i want to give vendor wise  **Allow shopping for unlogged customers** this setting, please help me

We have tons of products from vendors, and some vendors want to hide the price until users are logged in.

Comment: Generally, if you can describe a need, the answer would be yes. In the meantime,  Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Features to hide add to cart button from fronted for unlogged and unregistered users by vendor

Comment: Yes, you can do that.
There are two ways:

Create "Vendor" usergroup and set permissions. Then assign vendors to this usergroup. After that set visibility for prices to this usergroup in store settings.
If you don't want to use usergroups, then you can set visibility for prices to "Only for logged in users" in store settings.